# What types of objects can constexpr pointers point to?

Tags: c++, pointers, constant-expression

cppreference.com says:

> [A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration implies `const`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

But I tried to make a `constexpr` pointer hold the address of a `const` object of the same base-type but the compiler gave me an error:

```
const int a = 1;
int main(){
constexpr int *b = &a;
return 0;
}
```

So, what types can a `constexpr` pointer point to?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not with constexpr. If you said

```
int *b = &a;
```

You'd get the same error. i.e. "invalid conversion from const int* to int*"

We can fix that by making it a pointer to a const int.

```
int const *b = &a;
```

Now we can add constexpr, and yes, constexpr *does* imply const

```
constexpr int const *b = &a;
```

where b is in fact const. This is exactly the same as the following

```
constexpr int const * const b = &a;
                    //^^^^^
// this const is made redundant by the constexpr.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't compile because 'a' is a 'const int', and requires a 'constexpr const int' pointer to point to it.